# How to create modulefile for linux Environment Modules?

Tags: linux, tcl, centos7, environment-modules, modulefile

How to create  modulefile on centos7 for any software (ex. for python)?

path of modulefile is `/etc/modulefile`

I have two version of python ( python2.7 and python3.7).

I Create a directory for python inside modulefiles `/etc/modulefiles/python` , then I shoud create a modulefiles for paython as a following code :

```
#%Module 1.0
# python2.7 module file

conflict        python
prepend-path  PATH              ---
prepend-path  LD_LIBRARY_PATH   ----
prepend-path  MANPATH           ---
prepend-path  INFOPATH          ---

setenv        --_DIR            ---
setenv        --_BIN            ---
setenv        --_INC            ---
setenv        --_LIB            ---
```

My question is how can I get the right variables of `prepend-path` and `setenv`

Below is result of `whereis python` command, can we extract varable of `prepend-path` and `setenv` from it:

```
[root@mu modulefiles]# whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib64/python2.7 /etc/python /usr/local/bin/python3.7m-config /usr/local/bin/python3.7m /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.7 /usr/include/python2.7 /etc/modulefiles/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PATH` variable is the environment variable used to search for binaries.
You installed two different versions of Python, so each should have a different directory containing the python executable (`bin` and probably also `extra/bin`).

The `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is used to list the directories containing libraries. Probably `lib` and `extra/lib`, etc.

There are more environment variables that can be set, depending on the module you are trying to create. For instance, a `gcc` module will probably set the `CC` environment variable. Python can also have `PYTHONPATH` where Python will look for modules and packages.

The `MANPATH` environment variable is used to look for `man` pages whereas the `INFOPATH` is used to find Info manuals.

The variables that you need to set depend exclusively on what you actually want to use. It can be enough to just update `PATH` and never update the `MANPATH` properly, for example.